# Debian (crunchbang) enable audible terminal bell

Tags: linux, audio, terminal, debian, kernel-module

I've been trying to figure this out for over a month, with no real success.
I an running debian testing (crunchbang), and the distro has tried to remove all beeps/bells/etc.

I've tried using fancy solutions like `fancybeepdaemon`, `softbeep`, etc; but they have all fallen out of maintenance, and can't be compiled.

I have tried enabling the `snd-pcsp` module, and commenting out every instance of bell disabling I can think of (openbox's autostart); but still no joy.

Does anyone know how I can either get a terminal bell back, or play a custom sound when a bell happens (by bell, I am talking about the `\a` escape sequence)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, half a year and a clean install (deb testing) later I've found a working solution!

My solution was to edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and add two lines:

```
load-sample-lazy x11-bell /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga
load-module module-x11-bell sample=x11-bell
```

which gets a 'subell' working just like in Gnome 3, and is using the same file.

**EDIT 04JUL2016:**
A recent change to pulseaudio has removed these two lines from `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, at least on debian sid. It is possible to use `pactl` to set this as well, at which point you could make a WM conf enact the settings.

```
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga bell; pactl load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell;
```

Comment: `pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga bell; pactl load-module module-x11-bell sample=bell;` worked for me in Terminator on Ubuntu 16.04 after enabling Audible beep in Preferences->profiles but it didin't work for xfce4-terminal

Comment: @askonecki I have tested with terminator (in the past) and urxvt with sucssess.

Answer (score 2):

There are several places that this can be turned off, so check that all of them are on.

1. Make sure pcspkr is either loaded or built in to your kernel (and that the speaker itself is supported; it actually isn't on some newer machines)
2. If you use ALSA or PulseAudio, they may have pcspeaker as a mix control; make sure its volume is up and it's not muted (my laptop doesn't but my desktop does, so YMMV -- aplay -L and speaker-test are your friends here).
3. Your terminal has to allow it (setterm blength 1 ; xset b on (if applicable) ; also if you're using an emulator it generally will have bell or beep as an option somewhere -- I remember that compiz used to capture bell events and turn them into a window shiver, for instance)
4. Your shell can suppress them (eg tcsh has a set of variables that determine when bells do and don't happen; I think bash is more straightforward).

Comment: 1: Do you have any suggestions for checking that the hardware does support it? (on an acer aspire v5-171-6471) 2: With `pcspkr` enabled, I don't see any listing in `aplay -L` or alsamixer`, when it was blacked listed and `snd-pcsp` was enabled instead, I was getting an extra source listed in one of the gui sound confs. 3. I've tried manually running the setterm and xset, which don't help. and my terminal emulator (terminator) has audible bells enabled. 4. I think that bash isn't set to mute the bell.